Why we use gradient*input for producing the saliency map of a CNN?
The simplest way to generate a saliency map for a CNN, is to compute the gradient for the specific input as described here.
There is another approach where the saliency map equals gradient*input. I have read that it makes the saliency map cleaner but I would like an explanation why this is the case or simply the motivation behind multiplying with the input.
